# change meta-data after submission and stay at the same place?

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

i would like to change the order of my images in the meta-data,and also some text.
my app is already at the appstore.

if i change them now, can it change my place at the app-store ? 
i really scare that a change it will take me down ..

if someone knows foe sure i will be happy to hear .

another thing- does my "sales"-number, is updated in real time ?

thanks a lot.

```
does my question meet quality standard now? -NO! i need to add more and more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change your meta-data unless you upload an update. Or you can remove it from the AppStore and add it again (the App would have to go through the review process again).. The first choice is better.

Sales are updated daily.

Note: When uploading an update, they also have to review it, but your previous version will stay in the App Store until the new one is launched.